# Deferred evaluation in python

Tags: python, lambda, interpreter, evaluation

I have heard of deferred evaluation in python (for example [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/AlternateLambdaSyntax)), is it just referring to how lambdas are evaluated by the interpreter only when they are used? Or is this the proper term for describing how, due to python's dynamic design, it will not catch many errors until runtime?

Or am I missing something entirely?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dietrich's answer is a good one, but I just want to add that the simplest form of deferred evaluation is the `if` statement:

```
if True:
  x = 5
else:
  x = y    # huh? what is y?
```

This code parses and runs correctly, although the `else` clause makes no sense - `y` is undefined. The `else` clause is only being parsed - so it should be valid Python syntactically. This can be actually used for some simple code:

```
if stuff:
   print stuff.contents
else:
   print "no stuff"
```

In a strongly typed language this wouldn't work, because to type `stuff.contents` requires `stuff` to be of a certain type that has a `contents` attribute. In Python, because of the deferred evaluation of the statements in `if`, this isn't necessarily true. `stuff` can be `None` which obviously has no attributes, and the interpreter will just take the `else` clause without executing the first. Hence this is valid Python and even an idiom, that makes code simpler.

[Reference discussion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation)

Comment: I think you're confusing type systems and lazy evaluation in your 2nd example. "Strongly" typed languages can use lazy evaluation to do neat tricks. E.g. Haskell has a very strong static type system with lots of lazy evaluation! Unlike Python, the `if-then-else` has to type-check, but other than that the evaluation is deferred. For example, you can write `if True then 5 else undefined`, and this compiles and runs just fine (and the result is 5, as expected). That your `if-else` works in Python even though it doesn't type-check in a static language is unrelated to the evaluation strategy.

Answer (score 18):

Deferred evaluation is when an expression isn't evaluated until it's needed.  In most languages, you use something like `lambda` to make this work.  Here's a contrived example that shows part of the concept:

```
def list_files():
    for fn in os.listdir('.'):
        yield fn, lambda: open(fn, 'r').read()


for fn, body in list_files():
    if fn.endswith('.txt'):
        print body()
```

Here, `list_files` returns a bunch of filenames and a "thunk" (lambda with no arguments) which returns the file's contents.  The "thunk" is a deferred evaluation.  Using thunks allows you to separate your concerns:

- The for loop doesn't need to know how to read files, so `list_files` could be replaced with `list_ftp_files` or `list_zip_archive`.
- The `list_files` function doesn't need to know which files will be read.  With thunks, it doesn't have to read every single file.

In proper deferred evaluation, once you evaluated the "thunk" it would replace itself with an evaluated copy, so evaluating it twice would be no more work than evaluating it once.  There are other ways to accomplish the same thing, such as with classes and objects which cache values.

Deferred evaluation is a (relatively) common idiom in Scheme.  In Haskell, evaluations are deferred by default and you don't need any syntax to do it (there's special syntax for turning it off).

Comment: The lambda is deferred, but be careful about storage, as they don't capture fn as you currently have them: http://codepad.org/fXfIj364.  And another caveat: http://codepad.org/poXS7nc2.

Comment: That's a good point, and one of the reasons I stay away from lambda when coding in Python.

Comment: This is why I prefer inline functions + `functools.partial` to freeze the arguments: http://codepad.org/fwxLbl7l